# moment - calculate how long a user needs to wait before hitting a certain age

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I've been using moment to validate if a user is 15 years and 9 months old.

```js
var dobDate = moment($('#dobday').val() + "-" + $('#dobmonth').val() + "-" + $('#dobyear').val(), "DD-MM-YYYY");

var dobday = $('input[name=dobday]').val();
var dobmonth = $('input[name=dobmonth]').val();
var dobyear = $('input[name=dobyear]').val();

age = moment().diff(dobDate, 'years', true);

console.log(age); 

if (((dobday === '' || dobday === undefined) || (dobmonth === '' || dobmonth === undefined) || (dobyear === '' || dobyear === undefined))) {
    $('#qdobDate').addClass('form-group-error error');
    showerror('.dobDate.error-message');
    $('.error-summary').show();
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    validInput = false;
}
else if ((validInput) && (age >= 15.7499999997) && (changing === "true")) {
    member.questions.dob = dobDate.toISOString();
    go('/firstapp/check-your-answers');
}
else if ((validInput) && (age >= 15.7499999997)) {
    member.questions.dob = dobDate.toISOString();
    go('/firstapp/apply-before');
}
else {
    go('/firstapp/error/age-dropout');
}
```

After dropping out to '/firstapp/error/age-dropout' I want to be able to use the date of birth they gave me to calculate a date on which they turn 15 years and 9 months old.

I'm new to moment and I've struggled to find an answer through google.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check the working JSFiddle, it returns you the age and month with regards to DOB and current date,

You just need to take care of correct input and the date format.

For Eg: `var age = getAge("1998/08/08", new Date());`

http://jsfiddle.net/x9paT/932/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to match 15 years and 9 months, you might as well just calculate with months, rather than years (189 months is slightly easier to work with than 15.7499..97 years).

You can get the amount of months passed since the entered birthday (in months) with `moment.diff()`, as you already have used for years. `new Date()` will refer to today, and if we use `birthday.diff(today, 'month')`, we'll *hopefully* get a negative number (unless the person who entered the date is from the future). We can subtract this number from 189, and we'll get a new date with the help of `Date#setMonth()`, which would be 15 years and 9 months from the the entered birthday.

```
var d = 20;
var m = 10;
var y = 2010;

var birthday = moment([y, m, d]);
var when = new Date(); // Today

var months = birthday.diff(when, 'month');

if(months < 0) {
    when.setMonth(189 + months);
    alert(when);
}
```